# How do I check a checkbox with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have tried everything and nothing works.  I have this checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="WriteFormSelections('SearchForm', 'AccommodationType', 'AccommodationTypeSelections', 'All', 'AccommodationType-0', false, '_', true);" value="Hotel" name="AccommodationType_Hotel" id="AccommodationType-2">Hotel
```

And I want to check it when the page loads.  I have tried lots of things.  One of the things I can't work out is, am I supposed to use the id or the name of the checkbox to check it?

Here's my current code.  I have tried to use prop as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript) post but that doesn't work either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('AccommodationType-2').attr('checked', true);
</script>
```

Comment: `$('AccommodationType-2')` is looking for DOM elements of type `<AccomodationType-2>`, you probably meant `$('#AccommodationType-2')` (ID selector) or `$('.AccommodationType-2')` (class selector).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing a # in front of your selector.

`$('AccommodationType-2').attr('checked', true);`

becomes

`$('#AccommodationType-2').attr('checked', true);`

...depending on the version of jQuery you're using I'd recommend looking at `.prop()` too, which is to be used for property access on objects.

Additionally, as the other answerers have rightly pointed out - you do need to wait for the DOM to be ready by wrapping a `document.ready()` around your checkbox-checking line.

Comment: +1 for mentioning jQuery version regarding `prop` which was only added in jQuery 1.6. Here is also the links to the docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ and http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: You should use `('checked', 'checked')` and not `('checked', true)`

Comment: @deifwud: That doesn't matter. The `attr()` method converts `(checked, true)` to `checked="checked"` in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the # in your selector. Also, you it's a good idea to wrap the code inside a document ready call to ensure the dom is loaded before it is run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#AccommodationType-2').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/vMTvs/

Answer (score 1):

You have To use jQuery Id Selector (also always try to encapsulate jquery code in the document ready wrapper)

**Correct Code :**

```
$(function(){

$('#AccommodationType-2').attr('checked', true);

});
```

using  `$("AccommodationType-2")` tells jQuery to search for the tag as `<AccommodationType-2>`